# Drivers Folder doesnt exists in syswow64

Tags: wine

Recently i downloaded wine and i tried to install Direct X with wine tricks. it gave me error about drivers, but when i checked drivers folder it didn't exist. can anyone tell me how to fix that?

```
winetricks dxdiag
```

command gave me this error

```
mv: cannot move '/home/username/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/gm16.dls' to '/home/username/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/syswow64/drivers/gm.dls': No such file or directory
------------------------------------------------------
warning: Note: command mv /home/username/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/gm16.dls /home/username/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/syswow64/drivers/gm.dls returned status 1. Aborting.
------------------------------------------------------
```